# Algorithm for check a Civil Number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can someone help me to write a Javascript/Algorithm function that check if the Unique citizenship number is correct or no?

I want a Javascript function based on this logic

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_citizenship_number

Want to write a function that check and give follow values

Example

7523169263 — a male, born on 16 March 1875
8032056031 — a female, born on 5 December 1880
8001010008 — a male, born on 1 January 1980
7501020018 — a female, born on 2 January 1975
7552010005 — a male, born on 1 December 2075
7542011030 — a female, born on 1 February 2075

Thanks

That is what i did

```
var checkCivilNumber = function(number) {
  var coef  = [2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5, 8, 4, 2],
      sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(number[i]) * coef[i];
  }
  return  (11 - (sum % 11) == number[number.length-1]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not understand it That's why I'm asking here. Can you guide me please?

Comment: Yes, we can help you writing the code, but we cannot write the code for you. Please try something and show us your attempt, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkCivilNumber = function(number) {
  var coef  = [2, 4, 8, 5, 10, 9, 7, 3, 6],
      sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(number[i]) * coef[i];
  }
  return (((sum % 11) % 10) == number[number.length-1]);
}
```

- Coefficients were in reverse order
- After calculating the sum modulo 11, calculate the result modulo 10, so that 10 is changed to 0 as per the algorithm

Testing:

```
console.log(checkCivilNumber("7523169263"));
console.log(checkCivilNumber("8032056031"));
console.log(checkCivilNumber("8001010008"));
console.log(checkCivilNumber("7501020018"));
console.log(checkCivilNumber("7552010005"));
console.log(checkCivilNumber("7542011030"));
```

Here's a function for getting the details. The fields can be extracted using substring and then adjusted according to the rules. I'll leave it up to you to format the output correctly:

```
var civilNumberDetails = function(number) {
   var year = parseInt(number.substring(0,2)) + 1900;
   var month = parseInt(number.substring(2,4));
   var day = parseInt(number.substring(4,6));
   if(month > 40) // years from 2000-2099 have 40 added to the month
   {
       month -= 40;
       year += 100;
   }
   if(month > 20) // years from 1800-1899 have 20 added to the month
   {
       month -= 20;
       year -= 100;
   }
   // check odd/even of 9th digit using bitwise operator:
   var gender = (parseInt(number[8]) & 1) ? "F" : "M";
   console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + gender);
}
```